# How to use SOAP in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have a webservice and I need to extract some variables from there.
I have a DataSet inside him and I don't know how to use this.

First I make the connection, with SOAP_ACTION and METHOD, URL, etc... and then I did this, but still not working.

```
public void onClick(View view){

    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_LOGIN);
        request.addProperty("GetBaseDadosOnLineResult", "true");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_LOGIN, envelope);
        SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        Boas = resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(1).toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(Boas);
        bob.setText(Boas);
    }
}
```

So, my webservice has a `DataSet` with variables, I need to extract them to strings in Android Studio project.

Comment: good chance it is a duplicate of any NetworkOnMainThread error question, but you would not know that until you take a look at the error.

Comment: Thank you very much , working now!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use KSOAP library for consume soap
Please refer this http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/04/consuming-soap-web-service-in-android.html